# Why does BehaviorSubject always return a null value?

Tags: flutter, dart, rxdart

I have problem when getting value from BehaviorSubject.  I created a
screen in flutter that has two TextField and one Button and I receiving 
their data with bloc pattern.

But when I change TextFields values, The value of BehaviorSubject that
connected to TextFiled get null and when I change TextField value, the
value of two TextFiled that connected to TextFields gets null.

**Using flutter and dart**:

```
    import 'dart:async';

    import 'package:bloc_provider/bloc_provider.dart';
    import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';
    import 'package:sense_app_flutter/models/user.dart';
    import 'package:sense_app_flutter/resources/user/provider.dart';

    enum LoginStatus { SUCCESS, LOADING, ERROR }

    class LoginState {
      final LoginStatus status;
      final String message;

      LoginState({this.status, this.message});
    }

    class LoginBloc implements Bloc {
      final UserRepository _userRepository = UserRepository();
      final PublishSubject<LoginState> _loginStateSubject = new PublishSubject();
      final _user = PublishSubject<User>();
      final _usernameController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
      final _passwordController = BehaviorSubject<String>();

      Observable<LoginState> get loginStateStream => _loginStateSubject.stream;

      Function(String) get usernameChange => _usernameController.sink.add;
      Function(String) get passwordChange => _passwordController.sink.add;
      void changeLoginStatus({LoginState state}) =>
          _loginStateSubject.sink.add(state);

      Stream<String> get username =>
          _usernameController.stream.transform(_updateEmail);
      Stream<String> get password =>
          _passwordController.stream.transform(_updatePassword);
      Stream<bool> get submitCheck =>
          Observable.combineLatest2(username, password, (e, p) => true);

      void loginSubmit() async {
        String valUsername = _usernameController.value;
        print(valUsername);
        changeLoginStatus(
            state: LoginState(status: LoginStatus.LOADING, message: "loading"));
        // print("asdas ${username.last.toString()}");
        try {
          User user = await _userRepository.login("stevanus1997", "asdasd123");
          print(user);
          _user.sink.add(user);
          changeLoginStatus(
              state: LoginState(status: LoginStatus.SUCCESS, message: "success"));
        } catch (err) {
          print(err);
          changeLoginStatus(
              state:
                  LoginState(status: LoginStatus.ERROR, message: err.toString()));
        }
      }

      @override
      void dispose() {
        _usernameController.close();
        _passwordController.close();
        _loginStateSubject.close();
        _user.close();
      }

      var _updateEmail =
          StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(handleData: (email, sink) {
        if (email == "" || email.trim() == "") {
          sink.addError("Email can not be empty");
        } else {
          sink.add(email);
        }
      });

      var _updatePassword = StreamTransformer<String, String>.fromHandlers(
          handleData: (password, sink) {
        if (password == "" || password.trim() == "") {
          sink.addError("Password can not be empty");
        } else {
          sink.add(password);
        }
      });
    }
```

I expect the out from input but always return null.

Comment: Can you also post the UI code? how are you using this BLoC? also, I feel you should have a single stream for username and password.

Comment: i already solve my problem, that happen because i declare my bloc inside build function, can u give a example how i can use 1 stream for username and password, because i beginner in flutter

Comment: So you create a class called `UserCredentials` and add `username` and `password` properties in that. Then use a single `BehaviorSubject<UserCredentials>` inside your BLoC instead of 2 `BehaviorSubject<String>` properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like this

```
 final _usernameController = BehaviorSubject<String>.seeded("");
```

instead of

```
 final _usernameController = BehaviorSubject<String>();
```

You can provide a default value in the seeded function